# Displaying a dynamic list of objects from the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say I have the object:

```
var Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  name    : DS.attr('string'),
  is_baz  : DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

During a session with the application, foo objects will be added and deleted, and will toggle their `is_baz` flag.

In a template, I need to show the list of all Foos that are `is_baz == true`. As the list of foo objects in the store mutates, the displayed list should update dynamically. Hopefully using the store as the single source of information about foos.

I haven't any seen examples of observing a recordArray for changes to the contained objects. How would we go about doing this in ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the store's [filter method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter) is exactly what you want. To quote the documentation:

> Takes a type and filter function, and returns a live RecordArray that remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to your Controller for the template in question:

```
isBaz: function() {
    return this.filterBy('is_baz');
}.property('@each.is_baz')
```

then in your template where your display the foo:
    {{#each isBaz}}
       
    {{/each}}